# Regex for comma separated text

Tags: php, regex

I create a text field for adding tags separated by commas. (e.g. php, jquery, js, ruby on rails) The field is like the one on stakoverflow where you add tags for posts.

I want to validate the input to ensure that tags have been entered correctly. This means that users may enter only letters, numbers, spaces, and commas.I made the following regex_match but I'm not entirely sure if it's correct.

```
regex_match[/^[a-z, ]+$/i]
```

If the input contains anything but what I added in the regex I get a validation error when I submit the form. I have tested and it works when I put symbols like `' " ; \`

This is my first regex, am I doing it right? The language is PHP.

Comment: Won't that regex not match anything that contains a comma?

Comment: Have you, um, tested it?  Come up with tests.  Do they succeed or fail?  This makes it sound like you want us to test for you.

Comment: yes I have tested, it seems to work but it's my first regex. I just want to verify that I'm doing it right. @Tim, if anything other than numbers, letters, spaces, and commas exist I get a validation error.

Comment: I don't want to be irritating, so I'll not post "no" as the answer, since clearly you don't match any digits (required for numbers) or comma's. If you want to have a good answer, please make sure you specify very clearly what kind of input you are expecting and create some examples (e.g. can the spaces be anywhere?). Also, please specify what you mean with tags, there are more than one type of 'tag'.

Comment: @pwlstead, np, I added some more detail. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: What language is that in? It's not PHP or javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are a few problems here:

1. There is no php function called "regex_match"
2. a function uses (), not []
3. variables start with $. The inside of [] is an index.

The line you posted will result in a syntax error in PHP. Since you "tested it", it means this is not really the code you used. Please post the actual code.

About the regex, it's a good first try, but you forgot the numbers:

```
/^[a-z,0-9 ]+$/i
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using regex_match[] in codeigniter where you add your regex pattern in the []. Thank you for the numbers!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function, It will parse the CSV string into an array and then you can validate each tag individually using the [`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) function and discard the malformed ones ;)

Here is the correct regex pattern if you really need it:-

```
'/^[a-z0-9]+(, [a-z0-9]+)*$/i'
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that there was a function for csv!