# Regex for tags separated by spaces/commas, up to n tags

Tags: php, regex

I would like to validate a user's input of indexing tags for posts by running them through a regular expression in Codeigniter's validation library.

Ideally, the regex would have the following conditions:

1. allow only letters and numbers
2. tags will be considered unique entities if separated by space (any number) or comma (any number)
3. there should be a limit to the number of tags (for ex in this case 6)

There are a few partial solutions to this here on SO:

- [For alphanumeric tags separated by commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310141/regex-for-alphanumeric-tags-separated-by-commas)
- [Regex for comma separated text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165338/regex-for-comma-separated-text)

but they do not fully resolve my issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is validating, then this should do:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ ,]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,5}$
```

Same regex, but with comments and whitespace:

```
^ #beginning of string
[a-zA-Z0-9]+ #any sequence of alphanumeric letters
(?: #start of non capturing group
    [\ ,]+ #between 1 and int delimiting chars
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+ #again, any sequence of alphanumeric letters
) #end of non capturing group
{0,5} #allow between 0 and n-1 occurrences of preceding group
$ #end of string
```

To allow input with leading/trailing spaces/commas, change regex to this:

```
^[ ,]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ ,]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,5}[ ,]*$
```

and to further allow input with zero tags, change regex to this:

```
^[ ,]*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ ,]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,5})?[ ,]*$
```

Comment: thanks - if I ever need to change the number of allowed tags (for example maximum of n=10) how would I change `{1,5}` ?

Comment: The rule would be: `{0,n-1}` (note the zero! `{1,5}` was wrong. Sorry about that). Gimme a second and I'll update the answer with some comments explaining what the regex does.

Comment: thanks - just noticed it returns false if I enter only one tag

Comment: @torr: yeah, just noticed that myself. Should be `{0,n-1}` of course. Btw, should the regex require at least one tag to be present, or also allow empty input? And what about leading/trailing whitespace/commas?

Comment: awesome - one last thing - if I enter any number of tags and leave a trailing space or comma the rule is counting an additional element that doesn't exist - is this easy to resolve?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the PCRE regex :

```
^\w+[,\s]\w+\[,s]\w+[,\s]\w+[,\s]\w+[,\s]\w+$
```

Comment: This does NOT match ANY of the requirements given by @torr.

Comment: There's so much wrong in this answer, it isn't even funny anymore. Falsely escaped `[`, missing escape for `\s`, just to begin with typos. Next: `\s` matches more than just `space` and `\w` matches `_`, which is not allowed, thus violating requirement #1. Matches only tags separated by single space/comma, thus violating requirement #2. Matches only if exactly 6 tags are provided, thus violating requirement #3. Total violations/errors: 6 (if not more), things it does right: 0.